# Metamask stopped innjecting Web3. How to inject Web3.js properly?

Tags: web3js, metamask, dapp-development, web3-providers, django

I've been running a Django application which allows users to sign up/log in using Metamask. Everything worked great until recent breaking changes:

*In early 2021, MetaMask will no longer inject the web3.js API. You can still bring your own web3.js or similar library and use it with MetaMask. We will simply stop injecting a particular version of web3.js for you.*

This is what I did before.

**I DETECT METAMASK AS FOLLOWED**  --> This still works

```
if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    data['web3_status'] = true;
    if (web3.currentProvider.isMetaMask === true) {
      console.log('success');
    } else {
      console.log('detection failed)';
    }
  } else {
    console.log('detection failed');
};
```

**I ASKED THE USER TO ENABLE** --> This still works

```
var accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
```

**I ASK THE USER TO SIGN A MESSAGE FOR VERIFICATION** --> This doesn't work

```
web3.personal.sign(nonce, account, function(error, signature)
```

---

Metamask no longer injects web3.js. So I try'd injecting my own as followed.

**In my html header**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/web3/1.2.9/web3.min.js"></script>`
```

**In metamask.js script**

```
const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/<MY-API_KEY>');
const web3 = new Web3(provider);
```

I receive the following error when trying to sign;

```
metamask.js:51 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'personal' of undefined
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The metamask.js script seems incorrect.

There isn't enough code to test but you have to do something like this

```
const oldProvider = web3.currentProvider; // keep a reference to metamask provider

myWeb3 = new Web3(oldProvider);  // now you can use myWeb3 instead of web3
```

If the project is large you may want to replace web3 with myWeb3.

```
global.web3 = myWeb3
```